# SSL/TLS on Logstash syslog input plugin without XPACK/ NGINX or any third party tools

Tags: logstash, elk

I want to secure the communication to logstash 7.4.2. Im using Syslog Input Plugin listening over specified port. How can I enable SSL/TLS on syslog?

Regards
Ram

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Logstash Syslog input plugin doesn't support TLS.

You can use Fluentd instead which supports TLS encryption. Here's a working example with an Elasticsearch Output :

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 5140
  bind 0.0.0.0
  <transport tls>
    ca_path /etc/pki/ca.pem
    cert_path /etc/pki/cert.pem
    private_key_path /etc/pki/key.pem
    private_key_passphrase PASSPHRASE
  </transport>
</source>
<match **>
  @type elasticsearch
  host localhost
  port 9200
</match>
```

Best regards